# Problem 8 in Shiryaev's Probability 2 book

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I am having some difficulties with this problem 8. at page 6 in the third edition of the second volume Probabilty 2 of A. Shiryaev. I understand that the probability of the event $E =\{ \omega \in \Omega ~| ~\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\xi_k(\omega) \right| = +\infty  \}$ given below must be $0$ or $1$, due to the Hewitt-Savage Zero-One Law, and one should be able to get the value one by finding  some subevent $F \subset E$ with $ \mathbf{P}(F) >0 $. Furthermore I cannot see how the explict request  $\mathbf{E}|\xi_1| > 0 $ could be important.

Problem 8.

Let $\xi_1, \xi_2, \ldots $ be independent identically distributed random variables with $\mathbf{E}|\xi_1| > 0 $. Show that

$$
\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n}\xi_k \right| = +\infty ~~(\mathbf{P}-\mathrm{a.s})
$$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3823541/a-wrong-corollary-of-kolmogorovs-0-1-law/3823619

Comment: Also, $\mathsf{E}|\xi_1|>0$ implies that $\mathsf{P}(\xi_1\ne 0) > 0$.

Comment: @geetha290km, why did you delete your answer? It's basically correct, just lacks the case where the distribution in question is not intergable.

Comment: For the case when $E|\xi_1|=\infty$ I have added a reference. I don't have a proper reference or proof for the case when $E\xi_1=0$.

Comment: Thanks @d.k.o., that was very helpful.